# Projective Plane vs. Reference Plane

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I was told that the **Projective Plane** was also known as the **Reference Plane** in Projective geometry, but when I told my professor this, he freaked and told me I was completely wrong.  He said that the Projective plane is the *lines that go through the origin* that *intersect* the **Reference plane** at a *point*.  He said *"a 'point' in the Projective plane is a line"*, and  *"even though they look like lines, they are called 'points'"*...

This is word for word what he said, and he is the one grading my presentation.  So I am going to believe what he says, but I still don't understand this idea and the fact the Projective plane is NOT the Reference plane in Projective geometry.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dear Ellette,  Could you give some information on the course you're taking?  It might help people in formulating their answers.  Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what you are asking, but it seems that you are talking about two different *models* for the projective plane.

One can develop projective geometry from a completely synthetic viewpoint, which means that you prove theorems using basic axioms without ever referencing to what the points *actually* are.

Now, projective geometry can be seen in (at least) two ways. The first way is imagining the regular two dimensional euclidean plane, and adding a "point at infinity" for each set of parallel lines. This means that parallel lines will all meet at the same point at infinity (but a different point for each parallelism class). This seems to be what your teacher called the "Reference Plane" (although I have never heard that terminology, and google doesn't seem to give many results).

The second way is to call lines through the origin of $R^3$ points.

The link between the two models is easy to see, given the model of lines through the origin, you can map each line to the $R^2$ plane by taking its intersection with the plane $z=1$. The only lines that don't intersect the plane $z=1$ are those contained in the $xy-$plane, and they correspond to the points at infinity that we added in the previous model.

Comment: Dear Vhailor, I also found it hard to find instructive uses of the term "Reference Plane" via google; the limited results I got suggest that it is more common in applied projective geometry courses (and I was surprised to find that such courses exist!).  This is one reason that I asked @Ellette to say a little more about the course she is taking.  Regards,

Comment: Vhailor, thank you so much for your response.  What you said was very interesting and actually clears a lot of things up for me!  I have been researching Projective geometry for 4 days straight now and your answer, I have to say, made more sense than anything I have read about so far! hahah.  Thank you for such an extensive and clear response!  :)  and if I had a higher "reputation" I would "thumbs up" your answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @Matt E.,  I am currently taking a math history course (Math 212), and I am required to teach my class about Projective and Perspective geometry for my final project.  It is actually a course required for my education major, but there are entire courses, I believe, that teach just Projective geometry!  :)